# Custom Not-Found Route Fires Only Once

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, httphandler

I tend to dislike posting dozens of lines of code and assuming the community at large is interested in untangling my mess.  In this case I've exercised everything I can think to search on Google, traced through Glimpse, and Firebug/Fiddler, and what I'm left with is an occasionally working behavior, which is particularly annoying to debug.  So, I'm calling out for help.

Here's the gist: I've got a series of classes that handle MVC routes that are otherwise not found (and would produce a 404 error) thanks to @AndrewDavey.  I'm attempting to intercept the 404 and show data-driven content where any exists.  It all works until I refresh the page.  The request works on the first load, but it never fires again after that.

If you're bored or have an itch, the entire code block is below.

Setup goes like this:

- Add WebActivator via NuGet
- In your AppStart folder add a cs file with the code below
- Add a "PageContext" connection string to your web.config
- Run the app, the default MVC screen shows up
- Now add "/abc" to the end of the url (i.e http://localhost/abc)
- A cshtml view, stored in the database, will render.
- Change the view's markup in the database and reload the page.  **Notice no change in your browser.**

**the /abc route assumes you have a record in the database with the following**

- Path: "~/abc/index.cshtml"
- View: `"@{ Layout = null;}<!doctype html><html><head><title>abc</title></head><body><h2>About</h2></body></html>"`

I've got no idea why the first request works and subsequent requests don't hit break points and serve up stale content.

My suspicions are:

- Some voodoo with the VirtualFile
- Something cached (but where?)
- A misconfigured handler

Thanks for the help - here's the code (as I shamefully tuck my tail for posting this much code).

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Caching;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;
using SomeCms;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(Sample.Web.App_Start.cms), "PreStart")]

namespace Sample.Web.App_Start
{
    public static class cms
    {
        public static void PreStart()
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(InstallerModule));
        }
    }
}

namespace SomeCms
{
    class ActionInvokerWrapper : IActionInvoker
    {
        readonly IActionInvoker actionInvoker;

        public ActionInvokerWrapper(IActionInvoker actionInvoker)
        {
            this.actionInvoker = actionInvoker;
        }

        public bool InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName)
        {
            if (actionInvoker.InvokeAction(controllerContext, actionName))
            {
                return true;
            }

            // No action method was found.
            var controller = new CmsContentController();
            controller.ExecuteCmsContent(controllerContext.RequestContext);

            return true;
        }
    }

    class ControllerFactoryWrapper : IControllerFactory
    {
        readonly IControllerFactory factory;

        public ControllerFactoryWrapper(IControllerFactory factory)
        {
            this.factory = factory;
        }

        public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            try
            {
                var controller = factory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
                WrapControllerActionInvoker(controller);
                return controller;
            }
            catch (HttpException ex)
            {
                if (ex.GetHttpCode() == 404)
                {
                    return new CmsContentController();
                }

                throw;
            }
        }

        static void WrapControllerActionInvoker(IController controller)
        {
            var controllerWithInvoker = controller as Controller;
            if (controllerWithInvoker != null)
            {
                controllerWithInvoker.ActionInvoker = new ActionInvokerWrapper(controllerWithInvoker.ActionInvoker);
            }
        }

        public SessionStateBehavior GetControllerSessionBehavior(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            return factory.GetControllerSessionBehavior(requestContext, controllerName);
        }

        public void ReleaseController(IController controller)
        {
            factory.ReleaseController(controller);
        }
    }

    class InstallerModule : IHttpModule
    {
        static bool installed;
        static readonly object installerLock = new object();

        public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {
            if (installed)
            {
                return;
            }

            lock (installerLock)
            {
                if (installed)
                {
                    return;
                }

                Install();
                installed = true;
            }
        }

        static void Install()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<PageContext>());
            HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new ExampleVirtualPathProvider());
            WrapControllerBuilder();
            AddNotFoundRoute();
            AddCatchAllRoute();
        }

        static void WrapControllerBuilder()
        {
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new ControllerFactoryWrapper(ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory()));
        }

        static void AddNotFoundRoute()
        {
            // To allow IIS to execute "/cmscontent" when requesting something which is disallowed,
            // such as /bin or /add_data.
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
                "CmsContent",
                "cmscontent",
                new { controller = "CmsContent", action = "CmsContent" }
            );
        }

        static void AddCatchAllRoute()
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
                "CmsContent-Catch-All",
                "{*any}",
                new { controller = "CmsContent", action = "CmsContent" }
            );
        }

        public void Dispose() { }
    }

    public class CmsContentController : IController
    {
        public void Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            ExecuteCmsContent(requestContext);
        }

        public void ExecuteCmsContent(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            //new CmsContentViewResult().ExecuteResult(new ControllerContext(requestContext, new FakeController()));
            new CmsContentViewResult().ExecuteResult(new ControllerContext(requestContext, new FakeController()));
        }

        // ControllerContext requires an object that derives from ControllerBase.
        // NotFoundController does not do this.
        // So the easiest workaround is this FakeController.
        class FakeController : Controller { }
    }

    public class CmsContentHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values.Add("controller", "CmsContent");
            var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(new HttpContextWrapper(context), routeData, new FakeController());
            var cmsContentViewResult = new CmsContentViewResult();
            cmsContentViewResult.ExecuteResult(controllerContext);
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        // ControllerContext requires an object that derives from ControllerBase.
        class FakeController : Controller { }
    }

    public class CmsContentViewResult : ViewResult
    {
        public CmsContentViewResult()
        {
            ViewName = "index";
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
            if (request != null && request.Url != null)
            {
                var url = request.Url.OriginalString;

                ViewData["RequestedUrl"] = url;
                ViewData["ReferrerUrl"] = (request.UrlReferrer != null && request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString != url)
                                              ? request.UrlReferrer.OriginalString
                                              : null;
            }

            base.ExecuteResult(context);
        }
    }

    public class ExampleVirtualPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider
    {
        private readonly List<SimpleVirtualFile> virtualFiles = new List<SimpleVirtualFile>();

        public ExampleVirtualPathProvider()
        {
            var context = new PageContext();
            var pages = context.Pages.ToList();

            foreach (var page in pages)
            {
                virtualFiles.Add(new SimpleVirtualFile(page.Path));

            }
        }

        public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
        {
            var files = (from f in virtualFiles
                         where f.VirtualPath.Equals(virtualPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                               f.RelativePath.Equals(virtualPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                         select f)
                         .ToList();

            return files.Count > 0 || base.FileExists(virtualPath);
        }

        private class SimpleVirtualFile : VirtualFile
        {
            public SimpleVirtualFile(string filename) : base(filename)
            {
                RelativePath = filename;
            }

            public override Stream Open()
            {
                var context = new PageContext();
                var page = context.Pages.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Path == RelativePath);

                return new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(page.View), false);
            }

            public string RelativePath { get; private set; }
        }

        private class SimpleVirtualDirectory : VirtualDirectory
        {
            public SimpleVirtualDirectory(string virtualPath)
                : base(virtualPath)
            {

            }

            public override IEnumerable Directories
            {
                get { return null; }
            }

            public override IEnumerable Files
            {
                get
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            public override IEnumerable Children
            {
                get { return null; }
            }
        }

        public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
        {
            var files = (from f in virtualFiles
                         where f.VirtualPath.Equals(virtualPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                               f.RelativePath.Equals(virtualPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                         select f).ToList();
            return files.Count > 0
                ? files[0]
                : base.GetFile(virtualPath);
        }

        public override CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart)
        {
            return IsPathVirtual(virtualPath) ? null : base.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies, utcStart);
        }

        private bool IsPathVirtual(string virtualPath)
        {
            var checkPath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAppRelative(virtualPath);
            return
                virtualFiles.Any(f => checkPath.StartsWith(virtualPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) ||
                virtualFiles.Any(f => checkPath.Replace("~", "").StartsWith(virtualPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        }

        public override bool DirectoryExists(string virtualDir)
        {
            return IsPathVirtual(virtualDir) || Previous.DirectoryExists(virtualDir);
        }

        public override VirtualDirectory GetDirectory(string virtualDir)
        {
            return IsPathVirtual(virtualDir)
                ? new SimpleVirtualDirectory(virtualDir)
                : Previous.GetDirectory(virtualDir);
        }
    }

    public class ContentPage
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string View { get; set; }
    }

    public class PageContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ContentPage> Pages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question turns out to be a non-issue.  My oversight of the cache dependency in the virtual path provider is returning null for virtual paths.  As such, the view is cached indefinitely.

The solution is to use a custom cache dependency provider that expires immediately.

```
public class NoCacheDependency : CacheDependency
{
    public NoCacheDependency()
    {
        NotifyDependencyChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public override CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath, IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart)
{
     return IsPathVirtual(virtualPath) ? new NoCacheDependency() : base.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies, utcStart);
}
```

Comment: Are you in release mode or debug mode?

Comment: It wasn't an issue of compilation modes.  It was an issue of the underlying caching mechanism assuming null signals caching for the duration of the app domain's lifecycle.  You can test it by modifying the web.config at runtime which re-created the app domain.  At that point the page changes are reflected.